# How to express any element of $A_n$

Tags: group-theory

I know that $A_n$ is generated by $3-$ cycles; But if I take any element from $A_n$ how can I write it ?

Is that any element of $A_n$ can be expressed as a product of $3-$ cycles that means is it true that any element of $A_n$ is of the form

$(a_1 a_2 a_3)(a_4,a_5,a_6)$ or $(a_1a_2a_3)(a_1a_4a_5)$ or $(a_1a_2a_3)(a_1a_2a_4)$ or$(a_1a_2a_3)(a_2a_1a_4)$ or $(a_1a_2a_3)$

Answer (score 0):

The construction is given by the following proof (outline):

We know that any permutation can be expressed as a product of transpositions and we know how to do this. If $g \in A_n$, then $g$ is an even permutation. As transpositions are odd, this means that $g$ can be expressed as a product even number of transpositions.

Now we look at all the possible products of two transpositions (comes down to three cases) and show how to express each pair as a product of (in fact at most three) $3$-cycles.

Edit: We are clearly not unanimous on what the question actually is... Here's what I answered to. If you are given an element of $A_n$, say $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)$ or $(1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 \ 5) \in A_5$, then the above construction tells you how to express the element as the product of some finite number of $3$-cycles.

Comment: We may take "the construction" immediately for $3$-cycles, without first calculating it for transpositions, e.g., just write $(12)(34)=(132)(243)$.

Comment: I haven't seen a construction without using the transpositions to help. What's the method?

Comment: See for example [here](http://people.hws.edu/mitchell/math375/ans15.pdf), number $8.$

Comment: Ok, that's neat. But you still need a method for all the other elements of $A_n$, say $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)$, $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)(5 \ 6)(7 \ 8)$, $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4 \ 5 \ 6)$ and so on.

Comment: yes, you are right. But this is no problem, e.g., $(12)(34)=(132)(243)$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not true. The group $A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles, but this does not say that every element is the product of only one or two $3$-cycles. For example, consider the element $(123)(456)(789)$ in $A_9$. For a detailed discussion see also [How to show that the 3-cycles $(2n-1,2n,2n+1)$ generate the alternating group $A_{2n+1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271147/how-to-show-that-the-3-cycles-2n-1-2n-2n1-generate-the-alternating-group-a)

Comment: I am asking how should I write an element in general is it possible to express it as a product of 3 cycles

Comment: you asked "is it true that any element of $A_n$ is of the form $(a_1a_2a_3)(a_4a_5a_6)$ ...", and the answer is "no".

Comment: It's not always possible to express an even permutation as the product of two $3$-cycles, but it's possible if you are allowed to use more $3$-cycles. My answer gives hints on how to do it.

Comment: I don't follow. I understood that he asked that if he is given some element of the alternating group, then how can he write it as the product of $3$-cycles. The fact that $A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles does not alone give you the construction.

Comment: But $A_n$ is not generated by transpositions, as transpositions are not elements of $A_n$... And I don't know what you mean by "cocycle".